# CI_Model not found in extending class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't instantiate my models manually on my controller using require_once, following is the problem:

**Controller**

```
<?php
require_once './application/models/portion/portioncreatormodel.php';
class Payment extends CI_Controller {
  function sample() {
    $pc = new PortionCreatorModel();
    echo 'OK';
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class PortionCreatorModel extends CI_Model {
  function __construct() {
    parent::construct();
  }
}
```

When I load this model using `$this->load->model('portion/portionCreatorModel')` it works perfectly (in controllers or other models), when I load using require_once using this very same `require_once './application/models/portion/portioncreatormodel';` it works perfectly in other models.
Why doesn't it work properly on controllers? I found this in my `error.log`:
`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CI_Model' not found in /var/www/html/myerp/igniter/application/models/portion/portioncreatormodel.php on line 3`

**Note:** I already tried this require_once:

```
require_once APPPATH.'/models/portion/portioncreatormodel.php';
```

*Please, don't tell me the only way to solve it is renaming PortionCreatorModel to Portioncreator_Model, it is already working properly on models, the problem is on controllers.*

Any glues?

Comment: CI_Model is not found because you're including that file prior to the CI_Model class being evaluated in the process chain. You should never be performing a require once of files, and instead, should follow the MVC pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. By the way, how can I have several instances of a single model in this situation? Do you mean I should abstract it in a more high-level model? I am using it inside a fold, and although I could "clean" a single instance and then work with it again, I would prefer to just instantiate a new one

Comment: why you loading model that way and why you need multiple instance of model at  a time where one is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in your controller:

```
<?php
class Payment extends CI_Controller {
  function sample() {
    $this->load->model('PortionCreatorModel', 'pc');
    // Reference by using $this->pc
    echo 'OK';
  }
}
```

Reference: [CodeIgniter: Models](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)